# Использования hexidecimal в коде

Tags: c++

Какой особый смысл в том, чтобы использовать hexidecimal, для определения значения переменных?

```
#define SPAWNFLAG_NOT_EASY          0x00000100
#define SPAWNFLAG_NOT_MEDIUM        0x00000200
#define SPAWNFLAG_NOT_HARD          0x00000400
#define SPAWNFLAG_NOT_DEATHMATCH    0x00000800
#define SPAWNFLAG_NOT_COOP          0x00001000
```

Это как-то ускоряет работу на машинном уровне или может быть имеет какие либо плюсы? 
Довольно часто вижу такой код, особенно в игровых проектах. Почему именно hexidecimal? Почему не любой другой способ?

Comment: Так сразу видно, что это - битовая маска, и какому биту соответствует...

Comment: @Harry, о вот это то, что я хотел услышать. Сейчас буду читать, что такое битовая маска. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отдельные биты удобно задавать именно шестнадцатиричными значениями, поскольку они напрямую транслируются в двоичные, но при этом гораздо компактнее. Сразу видно, что `SPAWNFLAG_NOT_EASY` задает бит 8, а, скажем, `SPAWNFLAG_NOT_COOP` - бит 12. Однако ничто не мешает то же самое записать десятичными константами:

```
#define SPAWNFLAG_NOT_EASY          256
#define SPAWNFLAG_NOT_MEDIUM        512
#define SPAWNFLAG_NOT_HARD          1024
#define SPAWNFLAG_NOT_DEATHMATCH    2048
#define SPAWNFLAG_NOT_COOP          4096
```

В принципе, наметанный глаз сразу выделяет степени двойки, но все же это не так наглядно и позиции конкретных битов не так очевидны.

В C++14 появились двоичные литералы и возможность разделения групп апострофами, так что ваш пример в нем можно записать и так:

```
#define SPAWNFLAG_NOT_EASY          0b0000'0001'0000'0000
#define SPAWNFLAG_NOT_MEDIUM        0b0000'0010'0000'0000
#define SPAWNFLAG_NOT_HARD          0b0000'0100'0000'0000
#define SPAWNFLAG_NOT_DEATHMATCH    0b0000'1000'0000'0000
#define SPAWNFLAG_NOT_COOP          0b0001'0000'0000'0000
```

Возможно, такая форма получит широкое применение, когда, наконец, вымрет поколение, привыкшее к шестнадцатиричным цифрам.

Comment: Может и получит, а у меня, к примеру, от всех этих *многабукв* в современных программах просто в глазах рябит. А если серьезно, то hex-ы воспринимаются значительно быстрее.

Comment: @avp, ну мне, положим, тоже hex привычнее, но кто знает, что там новому поколению будет удобнее. Может, вообще ничего из перечисленного. :)

Comment: Ага, может еще при их жизни AI будет генерить машинный код прямо из ТЗ

Comment: @avp,чем не вариант.